# opencv bounding box issue

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have an image I need to draw a bounding box around and I'm trying to use the code at bottom of this post.
The issue I have is that I have tried to blur the blue box shape to remove its details e.g.

```
cv2.blur(img,(20,20))
```

but the blurred image doesnt seem to have a good enough edge to produce a bounding box.

I have found that if I use my code below with a plain blue square with sharp edges of the same size as the image below, it works just fine. It seems  the detail within the blue area stops a boundary box being drawn.

I was hoping someone could tell me how to get this to work please.

[image]

```
import cv2

# Load the image - container completely blurred out so no hinges,locking bars , writing etc are visible, just a blank blue square
img = cv2.imread('blue_object.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(img, 120,890)
# Apply adaptive threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(edged, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)
thresh_color = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# apply some dilation and erosion to join the gaps - change iteration to detect more or less area's
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations = 50)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,None,iterations = 50)

# Find the contours
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# For each contour, find the bounding rectangle and draw it
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 50000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)


cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image below is the yellow container after lower HSV mask range of 8,0,0 and upper range of 78,255,255 . Trees are above and to top right of the container, so hard to separate the tress from the container to put a proper bounding box around it.Happy to move to chat if that helps.[image]

Comment: if you use a "plain blue box", no problem you said. can you also share the pic you are getting problem

Comment: Hi Yunus, the image above is the one I was having problem with. When I put the above photo into Paint and make the container just a plain blue box of the same size, it then finds it with my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting to gray, throwing all that valuable **color information** away. You're also Canny-ing, which is generally a bad idea. Beginners don't have the judgment to apply Canny sensibly. Best stay away from it.

This can be solved with the usual approach:

- transform colorspace into something useful, say HSV
- `inRange` on **well-saturated blue**
- some morphology operations to clean up debris
- bounding box

That is assuming you are looking for a blue container, or any well-saturated color really.

```py
im = cv.imread("i4nPk.jpg")
hsv = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower = (90, 84, 0)
upper = (180, 255, 255)
mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

mask2 = cv.erode(mask1, kernel=None, iterations=2)

(x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(mask2) # yes that works on masks too

canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask2, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv.rectangle(canvas, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color=(0,0,255), thickness=3)
```

[image: output]

Comment: rename a few variables in my code to match yours, then just replace everything between `imread` and `imshow` -- if you've got a "larger" task, feel free to expose that in your question. you might get answers that solve the problem directly, rather than just improve on your approach

Comment: Hi Christoph, I got it working, thank you very much! My current plan was to put a bounding box around the container image - that would locate and give me the co-ordinates of the container. From there I wanted to use the container co-ordinates to give me the top right quadrant of the container, so I know where to crop the image and pass the cropped image of the top right quadrant to tesseract to extract the writing thats on the end of the container. I may also have to create custom code to put bounding box around different colour containers.

Comment: this here works for saturated colors... but if you have a gray one, you're in trouble. you _can_ use this to generate a ton of training data for an object detection neural network. that'll probably learn that you want colored boxes, but if you pay attention, it may suggest some other container backsides too, and you can feed those detections back into the training.

Comment: Hi Christoph, what was the thought process for choosing the mask values for your code please? Is there a rule of thumb thats used? Thank you.

Comment: the specific values I chose interactively with sliders. the general ranges are logical. HSV... hues on a circle. red is 0 degrees, green is 120, blue is 240. since 0..360 doesn't fit in uint8, OpenCV maps them to 0..180, and blue (240) becomes 120. I chose a generous range because the picture contains no red (0=360, i.e. 180) and the practical distinction between green and blue for this picture is somewhere around 180/90. saturation: surrounding vegetation is duller than the container, so that makes sense to use. 84 is 1/3 of the range. use what works.

Comment: Thnak you. The reason I ask is I had another picture of a container thats a yellowish colour, but it also has trees around it. Trees being green so having a yellow component to its colour I tried to use lower range of 8,0,0 and upper range of 78,255,255 with a degree of success. I'll try and attach the image by modifying my original question, or perhaps I need to open a new SO question?

Comment: best make a new question. ALWAYS post inputs. outputs are only of interest for seeing what's wrong, but entirely useless for replicating your issue.