# Difficulty extracting square shape from complex image (shipping container, doors/end frame)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm having problem extracting a square shape ( the square end of the yellow container in the image below ) from a colour image.

There is no visual break between the square shape and background which also has similar shades of colour as square shape.

You can see the trees above and to the right of the container that create the problem.
Ive tried to crate a yellow HSV colour bounds, but get a result ( black and white image below ) , but it wont fit the bounding box to the container end.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

```
   import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread("check1.jpg")
# Convert BGR ( not RGB ) to HSV as OpenCV works in BGR, not RGB.
hsv = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv.imshow('BGR2HSV__hsv-1',hsv)

# set range of yellowish colour, in HSV 
lower = (8, 0, 0)
upper = (78, 255, 255)

# Threshold the hSV range to get only yellow colours
mask1 = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

#erode the image to get rid of any background dross.
mask2 = cv.erode(mask1, kernel=None, iterations=2)
    
(x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(mask2)

canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask2, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

final = cv.rectangle(canvas, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color=(0,0,255), thickness=3)
cv.imshow('bounding box-final',final)

cv.waitKey(0)
```

[image: output]

enter image description here

Comment: Welcome to real world computer vision. For this single image it is probably easy to find an appropriate inRange (that bright beige tone), but finding a general way for any kind of image will be very very hard and much more complex than simple thresholding.

Comment: [in the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356479/opencv-bounding-box-issue) I suggested neural networks for semantic segmentation. that's better than a simple bounding box. perhaps a network could be taught to infer the corner points directly (instead of bounding boxes), or even those holes in the corner fittings, suitable for a perspective transform.

Comment: Hi, I did look at using a haar cascade to try and find the corner lock points - I had many false positives ( maybe my positive data set was too small at 100? ). I will look at a neural network as you suggest. Thank you.